# Python importing & using cdll (with a linux .so file)

Tags: c++, python, linux, file, shared-libraries

After one of my last questions about python&c++ integration i was told to use dlls at windows.
[(Previous question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1659159/python-executing-existent-big-c-code)

That worked ok doing:

`cl /LD A.cpp B.cpp C.pp`

in windows enviroment, after setting the include path for boost, cryptopp sources and cryptopp libraries.

Now i'm tryting to do the same in linux, creating a .so file to import through ctypes on python2.5.
I did:

`gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic A.cpp B.cpp C.cpp /usr/lib/libcryptopp.so -shared -o /test/decoding.so`

and the so object is created ok. If removed "-shared" compilation is OK but stops as no main in there (obviously ;) ). Of course libcryptopp.so exists too.

But when i go to python and import the "so" file, it said that the attribute has no object "decrypt", "encrypt" or whatever i put there. using "dir" over the dll objects confirms that they are not there.

external functions are defined in A.cpp as:

```
int encrypt (params...)
//..
return num;

int decrypt (params...)
//..
return num;
```

also tried using:

```
extern "C" encrypt (params...)
.....
```

Could anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Rag

Comment: How are you trying to "import" the .so library? Using ctypes?

Comment: You can use the `nm` utility on your .so library to show what names it exposes.

Comment: `from ctypes import cdll
mydll = cdll.LoadLibrary('/test/decoding.so')
mydll`



nm doesnt show them either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ compiler mangles names of functions.  To do what you are trying to do you must have the declaration prototype inside

```
extern "C" {...}
```

it's hard to tell from your samples what exactly you have in a source file.
As someone already mentioned, use nm utility to see what objects that are in your shared object.

Do not compile your object without -shared. Python load library does not support statically linked objects as far as am aware.

compile your object with g++ compiler instead, it will link to standard C++ Library, gcc does not.

Comment: thanks, seems like the real problem was using gcc instead g++ as it did crappy things. putting the prototype with extern "C" and changing the compiler did the trick ;)

Answer (score 1):

just to doublecheck something since you using boost.

```
#include <string>
#include <boost/python.hpp>
using namespace std;

string hello(string s){
    return "Hello World!";
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(pyhello){
    using namespace boost::python;

    def("hello", hello);
}
```

in python

```
>>> import pyhello
>>> print pyhello.hello()
Hello World!
```

just my 2 cents, sorry if this couldn't help you.

Comment: not using boost directly but i like this example, will test it when i got some more time. thanks!